# Devise displaying Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I set up a simple Authentication system based on Railscasts #209 and #210.
When i type `http://localhost:3000/users/registration/sign_up` , the signup page is displayed.But, a warning accompanies it:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: f.error_messages was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin. Please install it with `rails plugin install git://github.com/rails/dynamic_form.git`. (called from realtime at C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309)
```

How can i fix this issue?
Also, how to customize this route in devise?
something like localhost:3000/sign_up is a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well, to answer your first question, you can either install the plugin as detailed in the error message or you can do something like this:

```
<%- @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| -%>
  <p><%= message %></p>
<%- end -%>
```

Basically, it'll run through all the messages and print them out.

To answer your second question, you can do something like this in your routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

Comment: Thanks.First issue is solved.But for the second issue, i was asking about sign_up route.Right now, it's a lengthy route: users/registration/sign_up